# MongoDB: $text soft search

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

We are using MongoDB for a new project in which we have to preform text search (using the $text index).

Since our data have to be encrypted, without whitespaces, it seems to MongoDb as one word, so when I try to query it(with an encrypted text), I get no results.

For example (sure, in real life this data in encrypted):

If I had the following text on in my document:

“If someone loves a flower, of which just one single blossom grows, in all the millions of stars, it is enough to make him happy just to look at the stars.”
And I query something like:

```
db.book.find( 
{
    $text: { $search: "mill \"enou\"" } 
})
```

I would like it to find the phrase.

Is there any way to make MongoDb to accept soft-search?

**Edit**:
In the end, the Rejex expression with an index worked for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your best option is to use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) instead of the $text operator to do this

for the example you provided, the query would be:

```
db.book.find({text: 
     {$regex: /mill.*enou/  }
})
```

Comment: In terms of performance, Don’t we lose the benefit of the "$text" index by using regex expression?

Comment: @AvrahamL yes, regex queries will take longer, but as of MongoDB 3.4 this is the only way to achieve this